# How do i exclude certain links from being scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape only the links from the main body of the webpage but I also receiving links from the side bar of this wikipage which I do not want.

I currently only want to obtain the links under div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content" but I am also getting the links from under div id="mw-panel" as well. is there any way I can exclude the href from div id="mw-panel" to only get links from ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


def getHTMLdocument(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

url_to_scrape = 'https://wiki.sg/p/Category:People_of_Interest'
links = []

while True:

    html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')

    if soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/p/")}) == []:
        break

    for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/p/")}):
        if link.get('href') not in links:
            links.append(correct_url(link.get('href')))

    print(links)
    break
```

[image: the highlighted area of the webpage is the area where the unwanted links are]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `css selector` to select your `<a>` iterate over `ResultSet` to set baseUrl prefix. While you do this use `set()` to get unique `href` values only:

```
set('https://wiki.sg/'+link.get('href') for link in soup.select('div#mw-pages a[href^="/p/"]'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getHTMLdocument(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

url_to_scrape = 'https://wiki.sg/p/Category:People_of_Interest'

html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')

links = set('https://wiki.sg/'+link.get('href') for link in soup.select('div#mw-pages a[href^="/p/"]'))

links
```

##### Ouput

```
{'https://wiki.sg//p/Abdul_Shariff_Aboo_Kassim_(Singapore_Politician)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Adele_Tan',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Adelene_Stanley_(Singapore_Dancer)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Adelyn_Koh_(Singapore_Musician)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Adrian_Ang_(Singapore_Entrepreneur)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Aiken_Chia_(Singapore_YouTuber)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Aisyah_Aziz_(Singapore_Musician)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Akeem_Jahat_(Singapore_Musician)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Alaric_Choo_(Secretlab)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Alex_Yeo_(Singapore_Politician)',
 'https://wiki.sg//p/Amelyn_Beverly_(Singapore_Influencer)',...}
```